# I need to write a SQL statement with a sub-query and multiple inner joins

Tags: sql, join, subquery, cartesian

I need to join multiple tables for the data I want. However, two fields exists on separate tables that, when the query is executed, returns a cartesian product, grossly inflating the actual count of my data. I need a different column from two different tables. I can write two separate queries and then extract the data to Excel and manipulate it there (which I've done) but there's got to be a more efficient way.

Can I write a sub-query to get around this? If so, where would I write the sub-query?

```
    SELECT a.field
          ,b.field
          ,c.field
          ,d.field
    FROM table a
    INNER JOIN table b
    ON...
    INNER JOIN table c 
    ON...
    INNER join table d
    ON... 
    WHERE...
```

The above query results in a cartesian product. I am using SQUIRREL.

Thanks!

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: you can subquery in this way: 
SELECT a.field, b =  (SELECT b.field from b where b.JOINFIELD = a.JOINFIELD) FROM a

Comment: @sgeddes [Here's the best I can do super quick](http://imgur.com/AHjvPof)

Comment: Squirrel is only a SQL client application that can connect to many different DBMS. Which database are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

**Missing criteria?**

You are joining related `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` records and show them. There seems nothing wrong about that. If you get records multiplied, this may be because you forgot criteria in your ON clauses. Let's say table `d` is related to tables `a` and `b`, then you need `ON d.id_a = a.id and d.id_b = b.id`. Forgetting one of the two criteria leads to data multiplication.

**Unrelated data?**

Another possiblity is that two tables are not related. Say table `c` and `d` are related to table `a` and hold several records with detail data, but they are not related to each other. Then your query would list all combinations of `c` and `d` per `a` (e.g. a product bought from several suppliers and sold in several stores; your query would combine all suppliers that sell product X with all stores that sell product X). In that case you would have to think about what your query shall *really* show - or whether you want two separate queries instead maybe.